# D3.js Get Histogram / Bar column width

Tags: d3.js

I am generating a chart that displays published dates of documents in a set.

These dates can very greatly between days, months & years.

```
values = [Mon Jan 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time), Tue Jan 02 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time), ... , Thu Jan 09 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)]
```

So I am using "d3.layout.histogram" to group the document dates into 10 (or as close as possible) bins.

```
var x = d3.time.scale().domain([firstDate, lastDate]).range([0, width]);

var data = d3.layout.histogram()
        .bins(x.ticks(bins))  
        (values);

var formatDate = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%y");
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickFormat(formatDate);
```

Then, drawing the rectangle bars at a fixed 10px (A in Diagram) width as follows:

```
bar.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("width", function(d) {
            rtnW = 10;          
            return rtnW;
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); });
```

If I try and set the width dynamically, it is fine as long as the ticks are positioned evenly across the axis:

```
.attr("width", (width/(x.ticks(bins).length-1))-1)
```

However, if the ticks don't fit exactly then you get spare scale at the front & end (! in diagram) of the axis, which throws off the column width calculation.

So the QUESTION IS:

How do I calculate / get, the real width (B in Diagram) between each tick on the xAxis?
(If I could get back the dates on tick 1 & 2, I could probably work it out too. Can axis.tickValues help with this??).

[image: Column Width]

Many Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you can get the ticks of the axis using the `.ticks()` function. To get the difference in screen coordinates between the ticks, take e.g. the first two values, pass them to your scale and calculate the difference. It looks like the issue might be with the position of the bars though and not the width.

Comment: I think Lars's approach is do-able. If you know the length of the x axis (which you do) and you know your start and end dates/times on that axis (which you do (I would make the presumption that working in seconds would be best)) and if you know the number of ticks on the graph (which would be the point where my cunning plan might need help) you would be able to calculate the intervals. I think you might need to do a bit of experimentation.

Comment: All you need to calculate the interval are two adjacent points on the axis.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff How would get those two adjacent points on the axis? What sort of information is returned by .ticks()? All I'm getting back is a count... can't find a reference anywhere.

A code example would be really helpful here, if you can spare the time. Thx

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `.tickValues()`, which gives you back the values on the ticks.

Comment: Hi @LarsKotthoff .. thanks for your help so far.  It seems that xAxis.tickValues() only returns values that you have manually set. If I try and get the values that D3 has auto generated, it returns NULL. Thoughts???

Comment: Hmm, you could use the scale's `.tick()` function to get values then. The only problem is that it requires the number of ticks to be given -- you could try setting the same number for the axis ticks to make sure that they match though. If I understood what you're trying to do correctly, you should also be able to get the width by dividing the width of the graph by the number of bars though.

Answer (score 2):

Following @larskothoff 's suggestion for using the x scales .ticks(), I came up with this solution to finding the spacing between ticks that have been dynamically generated by D3's histogram.

As Lars said in the comments you can get the ticks from the scale (x) if you know how many ticks there are. We can get that from the xAxis.

```
var tickCount = xAxis.ticks()[0];
```

Pass that into the x scale .tick() to return the ticks (all the dates on the scale).

```
x.ticks(tickCount)
```

To get the x position of the first date on the scale, we pass that date into the scale:

```
var firstDate = x(x.ticks(tickCount)[0]);
```

To get the x of the second date on the scale:

```
var secondDate = x(x.ticks(tickCount)[1]);
```

Finally to calculate the column width:

```
var colWidth = secondDate - firstDate;
```

More concisely (and removing 1 for padding):

```
var colWidth = Math.floor(x(x.ticks(xAxis.ticks()[0])[1]) - x(x.ticks(xAxis.ticks()[0])[0])) - 1;
```

This works with all of my test data so far and seems like a solution. Suggestions of a more robust / efficient method welcome!

Comment: Good job to you and Lars. That certainly highlights something that I didn't know. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This should works :

`.attr("width", function(d) {
           return x(d.dx + d.x ) - x(d.x)
       })`